# How to make merge ranges work with images?

Tags: gembox-document

In the documentation I can not find anything about merging pictures within a merge range:

**Name  Price   Image**

```
«RangeStart:Products»«Name»
«Price»
«Picture:Image»«RangeEnd:Products»
```

Showing the products with name and price worked until I added the 3rd property Image with prefix Picture:

but my images are not rendered...

WHY ?

my data:

```
 private List<PdfProduct> GetDataList()
        {
            var products = new List<PdfProduct> {
                new PdfProduct { Name = "dodamax",  Price = 250.25, Image = File.ReadAllBytes($"./{DocumentFolder}/test1.jpg") },
                new PdfProduct { Name = "Comparex", Price = 230.25, Image = File.ReadAllBytes($"./{DocumentFolder}/test2.jpg") },
            };
            return products;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you executing the mail merge process, note that it should be like this:

```cs
document.MailMerge.Execute(products, "Products");
```

Or if that `List<PdfProduct>` is a part of another object that is your data source, then it should be assigned to a property that's named "Products".

Also, if you're still experiencing an issue, what version of GemBox.Document are you using?
Note that older versions of GemBox.Document didn't have special handling for fields with the "Picture:" prefix.

Last, are you saving the result as DOCX or PDF, try saving it to both to see if the problem occurs in just one format or on both.

Comment: The rendering of a list of PdfProducts works fine without images, thats not a problem! Thus my .Execute call is correct. I use latest Gembox with docx. In the docu of gembox I find nothing about images in a RANGE field using the mail merge approach!

Comment: The "Picture:" fields can be used just like any other merge field inside the merge range. That is not your problem, your issue occurs because of something else. Unfortunately, without reproducing your problem I cannot say what it is, can you perhaps create a small project for me which I could investigate?

Comment: The path for your images leads me to believe that you're running on Linux, is that right? If that is the case, does the same problem occur on Windows?

Comment: nah its windows 10!

Comment: ok the new {Products = xxx} which I once used was missing. Too less focus where I work...

Comment: That is the same as calling the method I suggested, with the named range. Anyway, glad you solved this one.